# RecyclerView Adapter not updating view content

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-recyclerview

I having a recyclerview with GridLayoutManager, it populating the grid properly but not updating the data.

Below is my code,

```
public class AppsGridViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppsGridViewAdapter.GridViewHolder>{

private ArrayList<App> appArrayList;
private Context context;

public AppsGridViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<App> appArrayList){
    this.appArrayList = appArrayList;
    this.context = context;
}

public static class GridViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    CompoundAppButton compoundAppButton;
    public GridViewHolder(CompoundAppButton itemView){
        super(itemView);
        compoundAppButton = (CompoundAppButton)itemView;
    }

}

@Override
public GridViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    CompoundAppButton appButton = new CompoundAppButton(context,null);
    return new GridViewHolder(appButton);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(GridViewHolder holder, int position) {
    App app = appArrayList.get(position);
    holder.compoundAppButton.updateButtonConfig(app);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return appArrayList.size();
}
}
```

Having valid values in the list, but not updating. Where CustomAppButton is a customview. Anyone can help me why it doesnt update.

UPDATE:
I calling recyclerview from my activity, below is the specific code

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MarginDecoration(this));
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
AppsGridViewAdapter adapter = new AppsGridViewAdapter(this,appList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The activity contains only recyclerview.

updateButtonConfig is a function in CustomAppButton class, this is where view is updated. getting data to this function, have checked the log.

```
public void updateButtonConfig(App app){
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(app.getAppIcon())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.app_icon)
            .into(appIcon);
    appName.setText(app.getAppName());
    category.setText(app.getAppCategory());
    price.setText(app.getAppPrice());
    appPackage = app.getAppPackage();
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation about where, when and how you update your data.

Comment: You just pass in the `appList` object. Where do you fill it with data? And do you change it later?

Comment: looks problem is with your customview CompoundAppButton.

Comment: The view updating properly other than gridview, i am using same view in other activities where it works

Comment: What is the code where you **update** de data?